# Google map freeze application in ios swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers, ios13.1.2

After tapping some location in `google map` application get freeze or crash.

Getting error like :

> Class **_NSZombie_GMSx_GMMResourceRequestProto** is implemented in
>   both ?? (0x2821d0d20) and ?? (0x2821d4060). One of the two will be
>   used. Which one is undefined.

**GMSCacheProperty**' is using nil or an insecure NSValueTransformer.

Comment: Can you provide a sample code that demonstrates the problem?